# onItemSelected() with nested switch... how to avoid it?

Tags: android, spinner, switch-statement

For my Android project, I prepare a dedicated class that listens to `onClick()`, `onTouch()` and `onItemSelected()` events (it's Controller of MVC) and the screen has several `Spinner` objects. In this case, when an event is fired, the algorithm must know 1) which `Spinner` is selected and 2) which `Item` is selected. Thus, it results in having nested switch like below.

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
    switch(parent.getId()) {
    case R.id.spn1:
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            // code
            break;
        case 1:
            // code
            break;
        case 2:
            // code
            break;
        }
    break;
    case R.id.spn2:
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            // code
            break;
        case 1:
            // code
            break;
        case 2:
            // code
            break;
        }
    break;
    case R.id.spn3:
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            // code
            break;
        case 1:
            // code
            break;
        case 2:
            // code
            break;
        }
    break;
    default:
    }
}
```

The sample posted below already gave me a headache. I'll definitely love to know if there is some ways (using OOP, maybe) to avoid this big mess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you want to do with these spinner positions. If you are doing completely different things with each spinner position then you cannot optimize further.

The best you can do in this case would be to create and call a private function for each item (or for each spinner, if one spinner does similar things among all positions).

Don't think that nested switch are bad, they are fast to execute, easy to read and maintain. What you should avoid is putting too many code in each `case` block. You should call private functions instead.

Answer (score 1):

I'd create a separate `Listener` class for each `View`.

```
public class MyClass extends Activity{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        /* Necessary View fetching code omitted */
        mySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MySpinnerOnItemSelectedListener());
    }

    private class MySpinnerOnItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener{

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id){ 
            /* Here you only have your inner switch statement */
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: OP has already mentioned *I prepare a dedicated class that listens to onClick(), onTouch() and onItemSelected() events*

Comment: And I'm suggesting a different approach.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a separated `OnItemSelectedListener` for each of the spinners.

If you don't want this, because they share some code together, I would still consider using one switch inside the `onItemSelected` method to determine which spinner has been clicked, and then calling a separate method for each of the spinners, that do your actual item switch.

But as long as they don't share any code, I recommend using different listeners for each spinner. I would also create these listener as inner classes, though it will bloat your class a bit.

You could also use the `id` parameter, as long as your adapter use [stable ids](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#hasStableIds%28%29) that are distinct between all spinners. Most surly this is not the case, so you are limited to the above two possibilities.